# TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined..return this._courses[courseName].push(dish);

Tags: javascript, object, methods, key-value

When this is ran a typeError is thrown and I just can't figure out how to fix is so it runs correctly. I tried changing the .push(dish) to = dish and nothing is working for me please help
When this is ran a typeError is thrown and I just can't figure out how to fix is so it runs correctly. I tried changing the .push(dish) to = dish and nothing is working for me please help
When this is ran a typeError is thrown and I just can't figure out how to fix is so it runs correctly. I tried changing the .push(dish) to = dish and nothing is working for me please help
When this is ran a typeError is thrown and I just can't figure out how to fix is so it runs correctly. I tried changing the .push(dish) to = dish and nothing is working for me please helpWhen this is ran a typeError is thrown and I just can't figure out how to fix is so it runs correctly. I tried changing the .push(dish) to = dish and nothing is working for me please helpWhen this is ran a typeError is thrown and I just can't figure out how to fix is so it runs correctly. I tried changing the .push(dish) to = dish and nothing is working for me please helpWhen this is ran a typeError is thrown and I just can't figure out how to fix is so it runs correctly. I tried changing the .push(dish) to = dish and nothing is working for me please helpWhen this is ran a typeError is thrown and I just can't figure out how to fix is so it runs correctly. I tried changing the .push(dish) to = dish and nothing is working for me please help
When this is ran a typeError is thrown and I just can't figure out how to fix is so it runs correctly. I tried changing the .push(dish) to = dish and nothing is working for me please help
When this is ran a typeError is thrown and I just can't figure out how to fix is so it runs correctly. I tried changing the .push(dish) to = dish and nothing is working for me please help

```js
const menu = {
  _courses: {
    appetizers: [],
    mains: [],
    desserts: [],
  },
  get appetizers(){
    this._courses.appetizers;
  },
  get mains(){
    this._courses.mains;
  },
  get desserts(){
    this._courses.desserts;
  },
  set appetizers(appetizers){
    this._courses.appetizers = appetizers;
  },
  set mains(mains){
    this._courses.mains = mains;
  },
  set desserts(desserts){
    this._courses.desserts = desserts;
  },
  get _course(){
    return {
      appetizers: this.appetizers,
      mains: this.mains,
      desserts: this.desserts
    };
  },
  addDishToCourse(courseName, dishName, dishPrice){
    const dish = {
      name: dishName,
      price: dishPrice,
    };
    return this._courses[courseName].push(dish);
  },
  getRandomDishFromCourse(courseName){
    const dishes = this._courses[courseName];
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * dishes.length);
    return dishes[randomIndex];
  },
  generateRandomMeal(){
    const appetizer = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('appetizers');
    const main = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('mains');
    const dessert = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('desserts');
    const cost = appetizer.price + main.price + dessert.price;
    return `Your meal is ${appetizer.name},
     ${main.name}, and ${dessert.name} and total price is ${cost}`;
  }
};

menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'wings', 4.00);
menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'tacos', 4.00);
menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'salad', 4.00);

menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 'steak', 10.00);
menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 'fish', 10.00);
menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 'pasta', 10.00);

menu.addDishToCourse('dessert', 'cake', 6.00);
menu.addDishToCourse('dessert', 'shake', 6.00);
menu.addDishToCourse('dessert', 'pie', 6.00);

let meal = menu.generateRandomMeal();
console.log(meal);
```

Answer (score 0):

`this._courses[courseName];` is returning undefined. Which means `courseName` is not found as a key in `this._courses`. Check your spelling, and `console.log(Object.keys(this._courses)); console.log(courseName)`, to see why `courseName` is not found

Answer (score 0):

Spelling mistake for desserts

```
menu.addDishToCourse('dessert', 'cake', 6.00);
menu.addDishToCourse('dessert', 'shake', 6.00);
menu.addDishToCourse('dessert', 'pie', 6.00);
```

```js
const menu = {
  _courses: {
    appetizers: [],
    mains: [],
    desserts: [],
  },
  get appetizers(){
    this._courses.appetizers;
  },
  get mains(){
    this._courses.mains;
  },
  get desserts(){
    this._courses.desserts;
  },
  set appetizers(appetizers){
    this._courses.appetizers = appetizers;
  },
  set mains(mains){
    this._courses.mains = mains;
  },
  set desserts(desserts){
    this._courses.desserts = desserts;
  },
  get _course(){
    return {
      appetizers: this.appetizers,
      mains: this.mains,
      desserts: this.desserts
    };
  },
  addDishToCourse(courseName, dishName, dishPrice){
    const dish = {
      name: dishName,
      price: dishPrice,
    };
    console.log('courseName',courseName);
    return this._courses[courseName].push(dish);
  },
  getRandomDishFromCourse(courseName){
    const dishes = this._courses[courseName];
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * dishes.length);
    return dishes[randomIndex];
  },
  generateRandomMeal(){
    const appetizer = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('appetizers');
    const main = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('mains');
    const dessert = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('desserts');
    const cost = appetizer.price + main.price + dessert.price;
    return `Your meal is ${appetizer.name},
     ${main.name}, and ${dessert.name} and total price is ${cost}`;
  }
};

menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'wings', 4.00);
menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'tacos', 4.00);
menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'salad', 4.00);

menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 'steak', 10.00);
menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 'fish', 10.00);
menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 'pasta', 10.00);

menu.addDishToCourse('desserts', 'cake', 6.00);
menu.addDishToCourse('desserts', 'shake', 6.00);
menu.addDishToCourse('desserts', 'pie', 6.00);

let meal = menu.generateRandomMeal();
console.log(meal);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is the below. You declare:

```
_courses: {
appetizers: [],
mains: [],
desserts: [],
},
```

and you call :

```
menu.addDishToCourse('dessert', 'cake', 6.00);
menu.addDishToCourse('dessert', 'shake', 6.00);
menu.addDishToCourse('dessert', 'pie', 6.00);
```

There is no field called `dessert` but `desserts` and this throws the error

The correct code is:

```js
const menu = {
  _courses: {
    appetizers: [],
    mains: [],
    desserts: [],
  },
  get appetizers(){
    this._courses.appetizers;
  },
  get mains(){
    this._courses.mains;
  },
  get desserts(){
    this._courses.desserts;
  },
  set appetizers(appetizers){
    this._courses.appetizers = appetizers;
  },
  set mains(mains){
    this._courses.mains = mains;
  },
  set desserts(desserts){
    this._courses.desserts = desserts;
  },
  get _course(){
    return {
      appetizers: this.appetizers,
      mains: this.mains,
      desserts: this.desserts
    };
  },
  addDishToCourse(courseName, dishName, dishPrice){
    const dish = {
      name: dishName,
      price: dishPrice,
    };
    return this._courses[courseName].push(dish);
  },
  getRandomDishFromCourse(courseName){
    const dishes = this._courses[courseName];
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * dishes.length);
    return dishes[randomIndex];
  },
  generateRandomMeal(){
    const appetizer = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('appetizers');
    const main = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('mains');
    const dessert = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('desserts');
    const cost = appetizer.price + main.price + dessert.price;
    return `Your meal is ${appetizer.name},
     ${main.name}, and ${dessert.name} and total price is ${cost}`;
  }
};

menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'wings', 4.00);
menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'tacos', 4.00);
menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'salad', 4.00);

menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 'steak', 10.00);
menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 'fish', 10.00);
menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 'pasta', 10.00);

menu.addDishToCourse('desserts', 'cake', 6.00);
menu.addDishToCourse('desserts', 'shake', 6.00);
menu.addDishToCourse('desserts', 'pie', 6.00);

let meal = menu.generateRandomMeal();
console.log(meal);
```